# Extjs dom and Ext.Element creation problem

Tags: dom, extjs

I create elements with Ext.element like this:

```
var table = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('table'));

    for(n=0;n<5;n++)
    {
        row = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('tr'));
        for(x=0;x<4;x++)
        {
            col = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('td'));
            col.update('cell text '+x);    
            row.appendChild(col);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }

    Ext.fly('data').replaceWith(table);
```

This works i FF but not in IE, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked in IE8 with ExtJS 3.3

```
var table = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('table'));

for(n=0;n<5;n++)
{
    var row = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('tr'));
    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        var col = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('td'));
        col.update('cell text '+x);    
        row.appendChild(col);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
}

Ext.fly('data').replaceWith(table);
```

Comment: There is no error, just it doesn't get created, it is shown in developer toolbar andif I click on edit and close edit, it seems as dom is updated and then is shown but that sucks. IE is 8.

Comment: @dfilkovi OK, I need more information on this error. I tested the code with ExtJS 3.3 in IE8 and all worked.

Comment: IE 7, I just checked my browser was in compatibility mode, it doesn0t work on IE7, in IE8 works, but that's also a problem form me, it needs to work in both browsers.

Comment: I am out of time for now and didn't found a solution. I will get back on it later. For now I dunno what happen there that the changes don't get shown.

Comment: I can't help you with this. Did you try to post it in the sencha forum?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Ext.DomHelper for creating DOM elements and working with them. Have a look at the DomHelper at Ext API Documentation and follow this [tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aDomHelper_Blog).

Comment: Yes, DOM works, but what when I want to add a custom listeners to elements like on click, context menu and other, as I know this can be only accomplished with Ext.Element or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you will just have a simple DOM elements and I don't know any way to get a Ext.Element from them.

Comment: To add, you can control your performance, by setting `Ext.DomHelper.useDom = false`, which increases performance. Check docs on how and when to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old post but for those who are still looking for answers, please check below code it should work fine in IE.

```
var table = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('table'));
var tbody = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('tbody'));
for(n=0;n<5;n++)
{
    var row = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('tr'));
    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        var col = new Ext.Element(document.createElement('td'));
        col.update('cell text '+x);    
        row.appendChild(col);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
table.appendChild(tbody);

Ext.fly('data').replaceWith(table);
```